# Nasm Error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers, integer-division

In my quest to learn NASM, I am trying to create a really simple program that does a division and outputs the result.

By the books, everything should run fine. I'm dividing 15 by 3, and it should automatically be stored in the AX register which I then move over to the ecx for output.

However, when I try to compile, I am getting the error

```
nums.asm:6: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
nums.asm:7: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with lines 6 and 7?

This is my code:

```
segment .text

    global main
main:

    div     3, 15
    mov     ecx, ax
    mov ebx,1       ; arg1, where to write, screen
    mov eax,4       ; write sysout command to int 80 hex
    int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel



exit:   mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx 
    int 0x80
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I keep seeing this form often:  `div     3, 15` this is not any valid INTEL mneumonic!

To divide 15 by 3:

```
xor     edx, edx
mov     eax, 15
mov     ecx, 3
div     ecx
```

For the second error, you cannot move a 16 bit register into a 32 bit register like that.  You need to use one of the following:

```
xor     ecx, ecx
mov     cx, ax
```

Or:

```
movzx   ecx, ax
```

Comment: Can you move a 32 bit register into a 16 bit?

Comment: Can you put 1 gallon of water in a 1/2 gallon jug?

Comment: Some of it... That's the logic I'm using as I scratch my head wondering why you can't put a 16 bit register into a 32 register